# Why can't I use window.open() to open multiple pages?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function input_check() {
  var num = $("#num").val();
  var sys = $("#sys").val();
  var tp = $("#tp").val();
  var urlstring1 = "";
  var urlstring2 = "";


  if (sys === 'QA') {
    if (tp === 'ACOs') {
        urlstring1 = "http://stackoverflow.com";
        urlstring2 = "http://google.ca";
        window.open(urlstring2);
        window.open(urlstring1);
    }       
    else {
      console.log(0)
    };
  };
};


$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#checkBtn').on('click', input_check);
});
```

I want Stackoverflow and Google open, but

- when sys === 'QA' and tp === 'ACOs', Google opens but Stackoverflow not.
- if I change the window.open order, the first page will open but second page not. 
  For example,

  ```
      window.open(urlstring1);
      window.open(urlstring2); // the urlstring2 and urlstring1 change order. Now it only opens the urlstring1.
  ```

Comment: likely it is to prevent popup spam.

Comment: `window.open()` doesn't really work that way, and I think some of it is browser dependent. For example, if I call `window.open()` after opening a window via this method on Firefox, it will essentially overwrite the active opened window with a new one.

Comment: to avoid e.g calling `window.open(randomURL);` in a loop...

Comment: Why would you need to do this anyway?

Comment: Sorry for my bad code... I am very new to JavaScript and jQuery. I will try to separate the code into two functions. If you guys have any advice it would be very much appreciated..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be due to your browsers popup blocker, which usually only allows on popup per user action.

Comment: It works! Thank you for your answer. Because my reputation is lower than 15, I cannot give you a vote right now... I will vote it as soon as I earn enough.

Answer (score 0):

According to [MDN Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) **Window.open()** , you also probably need to add a target:

`window.open(urlstring1, "target1");
window.open(urlstring2, "target2");`